# How to call a function (in separate file) from http callback function. app.get("/", callbackFun)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

File structure:

```
testAPI
    contactDetail
        dispMobNo.js
        myModule.js
index.js
```

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 3000;
const getCustNo = require("./contactDetail/dispMobNo");
app.use(getCustNo);

app.listen(port, console.log("server running on port: " + port));
```

dispMobNo.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", getContactNo);

function getContactNo(req, res)
{
    console.log(req.query);
    res.send(req.query);
}
module.exports = router;
```

Above code is working BUT I want to remove getContactNo function from this file and want to put it in a separate file. I mean, I don’t want to put any code inside/under API endpoint. I want to put getContactNo function in separate file and want to call from API endpointcallback function. So, how to do this?

Modified version of dispMobNo.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", getContactNo);
module.exports = router;
```

myModule.js

```
function getContactNo(req, res)
{
    console.log(req.query);
    res.send(req.query);
}
module.exports = getContactNo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.

Modified version of dispMobNo.js:

```
const myModule = require('./my-module.js');
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", myModule.getContactNo);
module.exports = router;
```

my-module.js

```
function getContactNo(req, res)
{
    console.log(req.query);
    res.send(req.query);
}
module.exports = {
  getContactNo
};
```

Above, I have assumed that, both files are in same directory.

Comment: @Pooja, you can. But, in that case, the module will have only `getData` function. I suppose, you will have more functions in that module. That is why I suggested `module.exports = { function1, function2 };` approach

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way

1. create one controller file in which create and export all your business logic functions.

```js
// controller.js file

export async getData = (req,res) => {

// your logic


}
```

2. import that controller file in your route file, and use function there.

```js
// route.js file
const Controller = require("./controller");

route.get('/api-endpoint',async(req,res)=>{
  Controller.getData(req,res);
})
```

EDIT for simpler explanation

```
// controller.js file
function getData(req,res){
 //your logic
}
module.exports = {getData}
    
// main route file
const {getData} = require('./controller.js');
 route.get('/api-endpoint',function(req,res){
getData(req,res);
});
```

Comment: function getData = (req) => {
// your logic} module.exports = getData; can we do like this?

Comment: no need to pass req, res obj ? Controller.getData(req, res)

Comment: Apologies, i forgot to add req,res params in getData, yes we can pass that
 
-- function getData = (req) => { // your logic} module.exports = getData; can we do like this?

=> i used arrow function if you want to export that way you can do that like this,

function getData(req,res) { /* ... */ };
module.exports = {getData };

you can read more at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: i have added code for this in my ans, please check last section.